# sqlalchemy core with postgresql in python, conneting.execute(..) error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am learning sqlalchemy core with postgresql database in python.

I tried to run the following script and got this error message:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, String

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/red30')

with engine.connect() as connection:
    meta = MetaData(engine)  
    sales_table = Table('sales', meta)

    # Create
    insert_statement = sales_table.insert().values(order_num=1105911, 
                                                order_type='Retail', 
                                                cust_name='Syman Mapstone', 
                                                prod_number='EB521', 
                                                prod_name='Understanding Artificial Intelligence', 
                                                quantity=3, 
                                                price=19.5, 
                                                discount=0, 
                                                order_total=58.5)
    connection.execute(insert_statement)

    # Read
    select_statement = sales_table.select().limit(10)
    result_set = connection.execute(select_statement)
    for r in result_set:
        print(r)

    # Update
    update_statement = sales_table.update().where(sales_table.c.order_num==1105910).values(quantity=2, order_total=39)
    connection.execute(update_statement)

    # Confirm Update: Read
    reselect_statement = sales_table.select().where(sales_table.c.order_num==1105910)
    updated_set = connection.execute(reselect_statement)
    for u in updated_set:
        print(u)

    # Delete
    delete_statement = sales_table.delete().where(sales_table.c.order_num==1105910)
    connection.execute(delete_statement)

    # Confirm Delete: Read
    not_found_set = connection.execute(reselect_statement)
    print(not_found_set.rowcount)
```

error message:

```
(postgres-prac) E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac>python postgres-sqlalchemy-core.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgres-sqlalchemy-core.py", line 20, in <module>
    connection.execute(insert_statement)
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\ba
se.py", line 1414, in execute
    return meth(
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\eleme
nts.py", line 485, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\ba
se.py", line 1630, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\eleme
nts.py", line 651, in _compile_w_cache
    compiled_sql = self._compiler(
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\eleme
nts.py", line 290, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compi
ler.py", line 1269, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compi
ler.py", line 710, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compi
ler.py", line 755, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visit
ors.py", line 143, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)  # type: ignore  # noqa: E501
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compi
ler.py", line 5317, in visit_insert
    crud_params_struct = crud._get_crud_params(
  File "E:\xfile\postgresql\postgres-prac\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\crud.
py", line 326, in _get_crud_params
    raise exc.CompileError(
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: order_type, quantity, cust
_name, discount, prod_number, price, order_total, order_num, prod_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You define your table as an empty table:

```py
sales_table = Table('sales', meta)
```

So when trying to insert a record with all those keywords, they cannot be mapped to columns and do not get consumed, hence the `Unconsumed column names` error.

You need to define the table columns in your `Table` creation. See the following example from the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#module-sqlalchemy.schema):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

user = Table(
    "user",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("user_name", String(16), nullable=False),
    Column("email_address", String(60)),
    Column("nickname", String(50), nullable=False),
)
```

Comment: many thanks for your attention, i try with your way. but error still exist. finnaly i try to modify part : meta = MetaData() and for commit the order i add : isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT" in variable engine